# Initializing a session properly after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm using C# code behind on the page in which I expect a user to log in from. At this time, assuming the log in information can be verified by the database, I set the session variables that i want to track throughout the session. I don't initialize the session anywhere, but by setting the session variables, this happens anyways. I don't have any errors with my code, but I'm not sure I'm doing this properly.

Code-behind on the page directly after successful login:

```
Business.User user      = new Business.User();

user.SetLabelCompanyId();
user.SetLabelUsername();

_labelUsername.Text     = user.GetLabelUsername();
_labelCompanyId.Text    = MySession.Current.CompanyId;
```

The way i call `_labelUsername.Text` is what I intend to do, but the way I call `_labelCompanyId` is what i feel would be confusing to someone unfamiliar with my project. It accomplishes the goal of creating the session, but is called differently than Username despite being used in the same manner. What I would rather do is:

```
_labelUsername.Text     = user.GetLabelUsername();
_labelCompanyId.Text    = user.GetLabelCompanyId();
```

And then somewhere before these lines initialize `MySession`. How can I do this? When I use the above 2 lines (with no other mention of `MySession`) I get an error that the session is null and redirect to the login page.

Comment: Have a look at [ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The session will be initialized when the user openes the site for the first time. But at this time, your session variable is not initialized. You nee something like this

```
//inside in your Business.User class (set reference to System.Web)
public string GetLabelCompanyId()
{
  string returnValue = String.Empty;
  HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
  if(context != null)
  {
     if(context.Session["CompanyId"] != null)
     {
        returnValue = context.Session["CompanyId"];
     }
  }

  return returnValue;
}
```

After a successful login, you can store the value to the session variable.

I very recommend to use a separated class for accessing the HttpContext and not directly in your Business Class.